# why my script in /etc/init.d with K symbolic link in rc0.d and rc6.d and S symbolic link in rc5.d is not working on shutdown?

Tags: bash, shell, runlevel

I'm writing a script which I want to run before every shutdown of my ubuntu system. I have placed my script named myscript inside /etc/init.d folder and then created symbolic links in rc0.d and rc6.d as K01myscript and S01myscript in rc5.d. But the problem is that the script is not running at all.

My Script @paxdiablo -

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LOGPATH=/home/user/Documents
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/decomission
now=$(date +'%T')

start() {
    touch $lockfile
    echo "[$now] System startup" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

stop() {
    echo "[$now] System shutdown" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
    rm -f $lockfile
}

status() {
    echo "[$now] Hi, you're checking status" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: What does the script do? And is the script's file mode set to executable?

Comment: You would be better off asking this over at https://askubuntu.com/. Problems with the script itself would be considered programming (and, if it *is* the script, you should have posted it) but this is most likely a Linux config issue.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for your response. The script is just writing something to a file in /home/user directory and yes it's executable

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for your advice. I will post it there too.

Comment: Did you test it using, for example, `sudo /etc/rc5.d/S01myscript`, or `sudo /etc/init.d/myscript`?

Comment: @lurker Yes I did that and it's working fine.

Comment: Then @paxdiablo suggestion that it's a Ubuntu configuration issue, rather than a script issue, is nearly 100% likely and the http://askubuntu.com site is the place to go. It would be off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks, @lurker. I just posted it there.

Comment: @paxdiablo please have a look at my script

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I was working on these lines today, so just wanted to check, did you add the script/service to run under init. You need to check the output of `chkconfig --list` I guess. If it's not listed then it's not configured to execute by the init system. For example:

```
[testfolk@jomohost ~]$  sudo chkconfig --list|grep myscript
myscript             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off    5:on    6:off
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the script you must set the PATH, for example:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thanks, @UtLox I tried that too but it's not working.I'm attaching my script, please have a look.